# при создании новой строки в таблице значение одного из полей становилось равным тому, что указано в dbedit?

Tags: delphi

при создании новых строк в таблице значение одного из полей становилось равным тому, что указано в DbEdit1? То есть написал один раз в dbedit и при нажатии на кнопку создать, создается запись в бд и в новые переносится значение dbedit1.

Comment: уточните на всякий случай, какие компоненты используете для доступа к БД.

Comment: в целом, кликаете на кнопку. берете значение из едита, добавляете новую строку в датасет, вписываете в поле полученное значение.

Comment: правда, судя по описанию, вам нужен не dbedit, а просто TEdit